# Configuration issues with PHPUnit and Selenium in PhpStorm

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, phpstorm, inputstream

I want to run a test on staging environment using PhpStorm and I am following this link: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-selenium-with-phpunit/. I have complete tasks up-to this code :

```
require_once (__DIR__.'/../../../bin/php/php5.6.25/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/');
class uatTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort(8383);
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.google.com/');
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    }
}
```

But now I am facing this issue:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:\wamp\www\phpunit-5.6.2.phar --no-configuration uatTest C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\test\uatTest.php --teamcity
Testing started at 2:10 PM ...

Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\test\uatTest.php on line 9

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\test/../../../bin/php/php5.6.25/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\test\uatTest.php on line 9

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite **.htaccess** or to change **read/write permissions** to configure selenium.